# Regexp to search and replace with transformed result

Tags: regex

In our project we had translations called like

```
Resources.Blabla.MooFoo.GetString("I am a whatever string!");
```

It was using Resgen, and now we want to use "standard" way for it.
We parsed out the source text files(removing special chars from keys) into resx files, and now want to search-replace whole project to change every call to

```
Resources.Translate("Iamawhateverstring");
```

The point here is that aside from replacing the call signature, which is not a problem, I need to parse out symbols like spaces, dots, etc. from parameter so that

> "I am a whatever string!"

turns into

> "Iamawhateverstring"

How can I do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex for spaces replacement:

> (?<=(GetString\(")[A-Za-z0-9 ]+) (?=(.*?("\)){1}))

(?<=(GetString\(")[A-Za-z0-9 ]+) looks before space character for GetString("[a-Z0-9] including space if there is one or more space occurance in string

(?=(.*?("\)){1})) looks after space character for ")

Comment: This may be correct, but I think it needs some explanation to be useful.

Answer (score 0):

I would replace it using this regex: [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/dM7dK7/2)

```
(Resources.Blabla.MooFoo.GetString)(\(".*"\);)
```

then when you get the capture groups:

```
Replace capture group 1 with "Resources.Translate"
Replace capture group 2 using captureGroup2.replace(/\s/g, '')
```

So essentially it is a two step process.